# How to setup a general 301 redirect that will ignore the ending url string

Tags: http-status-code-404, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

Is there a way to make any redirect that redirect based on the start of the URL? for example I would like this URL and all others like it ( the /57/userid/25516 is always different numbers).

http://www.example.com/site/ActivityFeed/MyProfile/tabid/57/UserId/25516/Default.aspx

To redirect based on (regardless of the following part of the URL string)

http://www.example.com/site/ActivityFeed/MyProfile/*will redirect no matter what else the string contains/

This would be amazingly helpful if someone knows the answer. Thank a lot guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having some trubles understanding where do you want to redirect it to. So this should redirect to `http://www.example.com/site/`. I think it might be what you want:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site/ActivityFeed/MyProfile site/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Try it out and let me know